# Блок на флексе или на гриде

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не хочется использовать скрипты.
Блоки хотелось бы чтоб имели одинаковые классы и разделить чисто стилями

Comment: Добавьте свои попытки решения (свой код)

Comment: когда-то писал такую вещь https://github.com/kliford/Portfolio-Slider - даже из сортировкой

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на `grid-block`.

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'i1 i2 i3 i6 i7'
    'i1 i4 i5 i6 i8';
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.grid .item {
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  background: red;
}

.grid .item.i1 {grid-area: i1;}
.grid .item.i2 {grid-area: i2;}
.grid .item.i3 {grid-area: i3;}
.grid .item.i4 {grid-area: i4;}
.grid .item.i5 {grid-area: i5;}
.grid .item.i6 {grid-area: i6; min-width: 140px;}
.grid .item.i7 {grid-area: i7;}
.grid .item.i8 {grid-area: i8;}

.grid .item img {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item i1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x140?text=i1">
  </div>
  <div class="item i2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i2">
  </div>
  <div class="item i3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i3">
  </div>
  <div class="item i4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i4">
  </div>
  <div class="item i5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i5">
  </div>
  <div class="item i6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x140?text=i6">
  </div>
  <div class="item i7">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i7">
  </div>
  <div class="item i8">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i8">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

По примеру из комментариев:

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'i1 i2 i3 i6 i7'
    'i1 i4 i5 i6 i8'
    /* Тут добавляем новые строчки */
    'i9 i10 i11 i14 i15'
    'i9 i12 i13 i14 i16';
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.grid .item {
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  background: red;
}

.grid .item.i1 {grid-area: i1;}
.grid .item.i2 {grid-area: i2;}
.grid .item.i3 {grid-area: i3;}
.grid .item.i4 {grid-area: i4;}
.grid .item.i5 {grid-area: i5;}
.grid .item.i6 {grid-area: i6; min-width: 140px;}
.grid .item.i7 {grid-area: i7;}
.grid .item.i8 {grid-area: i8;}

/* Ну и тут рассписываем.
  Хотя я бы подключил JS для этих "росписей" */
.grid .item.i9 {grid-area: i9;}
.grid .item.i10 {grid-area: i10;}
.grid .item.i11 {grid-area: i11;}
.grid .item.i12 {grid-area: i12;}
.grid .item.i13 {grid-area: i13;}
.grid .item.i14 {grid-area: i14; min-width: 140px;}
.grid .item.i15 {grid-area: i15;}
.grid .item.i16 {grid-area: i16;}

.grid .item img {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;}


/* "отделил" эти блоки, так что это можно удалить */
.grid .item.i9, .grid .item.i10, .grid .item.i11,
.grid .item.i12, .grid .item.i13, .grid .item.i14,
.grid .item.i15, .grid .item.i16 {border: 1px solid green; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item i1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x140?text=i1">
  </div>
  <div class="item i2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i2">
  </div>
  <div class="item i3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i3">
  </div>
  <div class="item i4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i4">
  </div>
  <div class="item i5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i5">
  </div>
  <div class="item i6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x140?text=i6">
  </div>
  <div class="item i7">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i7">
  </div>
  <div class="item i8">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i8">
  </div>
  <div class="item i9">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x140?text=i9">
  </div>
  <div class="item i10">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i10">
  </div>
  <div class="item i11">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i11">
  </div>
  <div class="item i12">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i12">
  </div>
  <div class="item i13">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i13">
  </div>
  <div class="item i14">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x140?text=i14">
  </div>
  <div class="item i15">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i15">
  </div>
  <div class="item i16">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70x70?text=i16">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если их больше 8? как продолжить? или создавать новый див с .grid?

Comment: Смотря как удобнее и что требуется. Если есть конкретный пример, то пришлите скриншот - "сверстаю")

Comment: да просто еще блоки https://codepen.io/Daaner/pen/ZwRrGj только без повторного .grid.

Comment: А, кажется понял. Сейчас напишу.